# Exception in Hbase table creation using Java program

Tags: java, hbase

While writing Java program in eclipse ide to create hbase tables, I got this error, even though I added commons_lang-3.3.1.jar file error exists.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

> ```
> starting...
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants.<clinit>(HConstants.java:717)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionKey.<clinit>(HConnectionManager.java:446)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:199)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:151)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:129)
>   at HBaseTest.main(HBaseTest.java:14)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
>   ... 6 more
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils**. It clearly tells you the problem. Add apache commons jar to your project and re-run it.

Comment: @user1965532 : It's a good practice to mark an answer if it resolved the issue. This will help others to benefit form it.